java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: CreationExtras must have a value by `SAVED_STATE_REGISTRY_OWNER_KEY` in UI tests when mocking firebase user(FIXED)
When running UI tests with hilt, I encounter the exception above. I removed view model and state listener implementations in order to debug properly but to no avail
Class definition
class CustomAuthStateListener(
    private val auth: FirebaseAuth
) {}

View model
@HiltViewModel
class NavHostViewModel @Inject constructor(
    authStateListener: CustomAuthStateListener
): ViewModel() {}

Screen
@Composable
fun MyNavHost(
    viewModel: NavHostViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {}

MainActivity
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            MyNavHost(onError = {})
        }
    }
}

Main nav host module
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
class NavHostModule {
    @Provides
    fun provideCustomAuthStateListener(): CustomAuthStateListener =
        CustomAuthStateListener(Firebase.auth)
}

Test code
@UninstallModules(NavHostModule::class)
@HiltAndroidTest
class Auth2HomeNavTests {
    @get: Rule(order = 0)
    var hiltRule = HiltAndroidRule(this)
    @get: Rule(order = 1)
    val composeRule = createAndroidComposeRule<MainActivity>()

    @Module
    @InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
    object NavHostTestModule {
        @Singleton
        @Provides
        fun provideCustomAuthStateListener(): CustomAuthStateListener {
            val mockFirebaseAuth = mockk<FirebaseAuth> {
                every { currentUser } returns mockk<FirebaseUser> {
                    every { uid } returns "test_uid"
                    every { displayName } returns "Test User"
                }
            }
            return CustomAuthStateListener(mockFirebaseAuth)
        }
    }

EDIT
Notably, this error was only occuring when i tried to mockk uid or display name of FirebaseUser. So i fixed it by installing a different mockk version
